# Is it possible to define common View Attributes in my Rails Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm pretty new to Rails, so please point me in the right direction if this is a terrible idea.

I'd like to add some attributes to my model members, which will be automatically added as data- attributes when rendered in the view.

For example, if I have a decimal field called "percent_complete", I'd like to include an attribute called "role" right in the model, that I would in turn render into data-role="percent"

So... in the model, I'd want to see something like this

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  def fieldAttributes
    [
     "percent_complete" => { role: 'percent'}
    ]
  end

  attr_accessible :percent_complete, :fieldAttributes
end
```

then in my view:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :percent_complete, "% Complete" %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :percent_complete %>
  </div>
```

The goal would be for the view to render something like this

```
<input name="percent_complete" data-role="percent" />
```

This would let me mark that field as a percent column, and then use javascript to catch all such fields and treat them accordingly, without having to worry about include data: { ... } in every future view of that field.

I've been researching overriding text_area in FormBuilder, but I can't seem to find good documentation on how to do that.

Comment: That's not a *terrible* idea, but it's not a great one either. You shouldn't have view-specific code (and certainly not HTML-specific code) in your models. Models are as back-end as you get, they're not meant to store your display logic. Typically you would either put this data in a helper method, or define some kind of form builder which could add the data attributes based on model meta-data.

Comment: I would move this from the model, and to the helper...